# 'Why has it been removed' or 'why it has been removed'?

Tags: grammar, word-order, questions, subject-verb-inversion

Would you mind telling me which sentence is correct:

- 'Why has it been removed?'

  - From the grammar standpoint, it looks equally to 'Why do you think so?', right?
- 'Why it has been removed?'

Thank you.

Comment: The first is a sentence.  The second is not.

Comment: Your first example is correct. As a direct alternant to it, your second example is wrong since this kind of main clause interrogative requires subject-auxiliary inversion. It would be OK as an echo question, or as a subordinate interrogative, e.g. "I don't know [why it has been removed]".